# How to measure text width with `italic` font style?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I am using convas context `measureText` to get the width of my text on the canvas. Below is the code:

```
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fontWeight = FONT_WEIGHT;
    ctx.font = `bolder italic ${fontsize}px`;

    const textWidth = ctx.measureText(text).width;
```

the problem is that if the font style is `italic`, the right of the text will be off boundary. That because `measureText` doesn't take `italic` into account. How can I calculate the text width for `italic` style?

Below are two screenshots for `italic` font on convas. The first one is the text without italic while the second one is with italic. You can see that the second one has a little off boundaries.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26296434/html-italic-letters-protrude-from-their-container-and-may-be-cut-by-the-next-co

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem inherent to italic rendering of fonts and their container box.
I am not a specialist and won't extend on the subject, which has already been treated in this [Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49475419/how-to-measure-text-width-with-italic-font-style) about DOM + CSS. Simply note that 2DCanvas `measureText` also suffers from this same problem.

The only workaround I can think of is going through an svg element, which offers better graphical bounding box representation through its `getBBox` method.

```js
// Calculate the BBox of a text through an svg Element
function getTextBox(txt, x, y) {
  var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'svg');
  var text = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'text');
  // so we don't see the svg element in page
  svg.style = 'position: absolute; z-index:-1; width:0; height: 0';
  text.setAttribute('x', x || 0);
  text.setAttribute('y', y || 0);
  text.setAttribute('text-anchor', getAlignment(this.textAlign));
  text.setAttribute('alignment-baseline', this.textBaseline);
  text.style.font = this.font;
  text.textContent = txt;
  svg.appendChild(text);
  document.body.appendChild(svg);
  var box = text.getBBox();
  document.body.removeChild(svg);
  return box;

  // convert CSS text-align notation to correpsonding SVG text-anchor
  function getAlignment(css) {
    return {
      'left': 'start',
      'right': 'end',
      'center': 'middle'
    }[css] || '';

  }
}
// attach it to the proto so it's easier to grab context's current status
Object.defineProperty(CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype, 'getTextBox', {get: function() {return getTextBox;}});


var x = 20,
  y = 100;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.font = 'bolder italic 100px serif';
var txt = 'Right';
ctx.fillText(txt, x, y);
// red => ctx.measureText
var m_width = ctx.measureText(txt).width;
ctx.strokeStyle = 'red';
ctx.strokeRect(x, 0, m_width, y);
ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';
// green => svg.getBBox
var box = ctx.getTextBox(txt, x, y);
ctx.strokeRect(box.x, box.y, box.width, box.height);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: This is really cool it works pretty well in a lot of browsers. I've been using this for a long time, but I was really unlucky to find one platform where this doesn't work :(. It's not working on iOS 13+ in a Webview (it did in previous versions of iOS). Any idea why it's not working anymore or what I could do?

Answer (score 0):

Set `ctx.font` first. The result of `ctx.measureText` is based on the context's current font, the same one you'd see if you were drawing. Do a `ctx.fillText` to check you have the font set correctly, I find the syntax is easy to get wrong.

Comment: I already did `ctx.font` before call `ctx.measureText` and I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to load your text into a hidden HTML div and get the calculated width.

Comment: DOM is subject to the same limitations here